# Update rows in table A with all different data from table B

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying update rows in a table `A`, based on rows from table `B`. Table `A` looks like this:

```
a_id |   NAME    | VALUE |
--------------------------
1   |   n1      |  NULL  |
2   |   n2      |  NULL  |
```

and table `B` looks like this:

```
b_id   |   VALUE     | 
----------------------
1     |   var1       |
2     |   var2       |
3     |   var3       |
```

How can I get the table `A` updated to this:

```
a_id |   NAME    | VALUE |
--------------------------
1   |   n1      |  var1  |
2   |   n2      |  var1  |
3   |   n1      |  var2  |
4   |   n1      |  var3  |
5   |   n2      |  var2  |
6   |   n2      |  var3  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to create a new table AA with the same structure as A
and do

```
Insert into AA Select A._id,a.NAME,b.Value From A, B
```

then drop A and rename AA to A or empty A and select into it from AA

Can't just be an update statement as records require inserting as well.

This is called a cartesian product and is usually an error. Please understand you end up with number of rows in A * number of rows in B. 2 * 3 isn't a problem, 2,000,000 * 3,000,000...